# How to prevent component re-render while using redux/reselect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I'm receiving frequent updates to my state and its causing some unwanted re-renders in components that are not accessing the changing state properties.

Component A and B are created in the same way, component A has the valueKeys ['speed', 'time'] and component B has no valueKeys [].

When the speed and time are updated one more value is added to each array, component A re-renders as expected, but component B also re-renders.

I think this is occurring because the valuesSelector input for makeValuesSelector reference is changing? Although the value is an empty array.

Is there any way to prevent component B from re-rendering in this scenario?

State

```
{
 speed: [ 5, 4, 6],
 time: [ 1, 2, 3]
}
```

ValueKeys

```
[ 'speed', 'time']
```

Selector

```
const valuesSelector = state => state.values;
const keysSelector= (state, props) => props.valueKeys;

const makeValuesSelector = () =>
  createSelector(
    [valuesSelector, keysSelector],
    (values, keys) => {
      let usedValues = {};
      keys.forEach(key => {
        if (values[key]) {
          usedValues[key] = values[key];
        }
      });
      return usedValues;
    }
  );
```

Component

```
const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const valuesSelector = makeValuesSelector();
  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    values: valuesSelector(state, props),
  });
  return mapStateToProps;
};
```

Comment: what's "Component A" and "Component B"?

Comment: An instance of the component that's using the MakeMapStateToProps - Was just trying to limit the amount of code in the question.

Comment: Are you using `makeMapStateToProps` in both A & B?

Comment: Yes, using it in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I came back to this issue as it was causing a significant performance bottleneck. I solved this issue by using a custom equality check in the selector to check if the objects inside the state have changed.

If the objects that the component requires have not changed inside state, then the makeValuesSelector will not run due to the custom equality check preventing it. Since the makeValuesSelector has not been run then it will prevent the component from re-rendering. In relation to the case I describe above, component B would not re-render.

```
const valuesSelector = state => state.values;
const keysSelector= (state, props) => props.valueKeys;

const equalityCheckShallow = (currentVal, previousVal) => {
  let noUpdate = true;
  Object.keys(currentVal).forEach(key => {
    if (currentVal[key] !== previousVal[key]) {
      noUpdate = false;
    }
  });
  return noUpdate;
};

const createSelectorWithShallowCompare = createSelectorCreator(defaultMemoize, equalityCheckShallow);

const makeValuesSelector = () =>
  createSelectorWithShallowCompare(
    [valuesSelector, keysSelector],
    (values, keys) => {
      let usedValues = {};
      keys.forEach(key => {
        if (values[key]) {
          usedValues[key] = values[key];
        }
      });
      return usedValues;
    }
  );
```

Hopefully this may help someone in the future.